# Rails: Better understanding dynamic scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scopes, named-scopes, anonymous-scope

This is my "dynamic" scope:

```
  def all_games(conditions = {})
    scope = games.includes(:stats).scoped {}
    scope = scope.where sport_position_id: conditions[:sport_position_id] unless conditions[:sport_position_id].nil?
    scope = scope.where sport_id: conditions[:sport_id] unless conditions[:sport_id].nil?
    scope = scope.where team: conditions[:team]
    scope.order(:date)
  end
```

The method above is in a module that is included with my `User` model.

So you would access this in code, like so:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.all_games(sport_position_id: params[:sport_position_id], sport_id: current_sport.id, team: params[:team])
```

When doing some Google searching for dynamic scopes, I came across Ryan Bate's RailsCast on `anonymous scopes` (http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes). I modified it since I am using Rails 3, but was wondering, if I was on the right path when it comes to writing dynamic scopes?

I find myself sometimes writing dynamic scopes because of the nature of some complex API's I am writing.

Comment: Is your question about whether this is the correct syntax for dynamic scopes or is it more of a what-is-the-best-practices type of question?

Comment: @RajeshKrReddy - I wouldn't mind the answer to both of your questions